# How could I customize preview window coloring with results from Ripgrep and fzf?

Tags: vimrc, plugin-fzf

I am just getting into vim and I'm trying to get the preview window for my Rg results to show up with nice looking colors. Currently I have most of the stuff looking nice; here is a picture of where I currently am:

[image]

This is in my vimrc for how I setup the Rg with quickfix window:

```
  command! -bang -nargs=* Rg
    \ call fzf#vim#grep('rg --smart-case --line-number --no-heading -- 
      color=always --colors "path:fg:93,169,245" --colors 
      "line:fg:128,128,128" --colors "match:fg:195,232,141" --no-hidden 
      -- ignore '.shelles    cape(<q-args>),
    \ 0,
    \ fzf#vim#with_preview({'options': '-e --delimiter : --nth 3..'}),
    \ <bang>0)
```

What settings could I tweak in order to get the preview window to be consistent with the normal text in the editor? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I would suggest you to use leaderf(plugin like fzf) with popup window, it looks the same as original. I haven't tried with rg, only with lines. I tend to believe it works.

Comment: I wonder if it’s not all the color settings you’re passing to rg? I don’t know fzf all that well, but it can be difficult to properly color text thats not going to an actual terminal (eg when its being captured into a file/by a function call)

Answer (score 1):

If installed, fzf vim uses [`bat`](https://github.com/sharkdp/bat) to add syntax highlighting to the preview. `bat` comes with several themes available. You can choose a theme by setting the `BAT_THEME` environment variable. For example, you can add this line to your `.bashrc` or `.zshrc` to set the `TwoDark` theme:

```
 export BAT_THEME="TwoDark"
```

To preview the available themes run in your shell:

```
bat --list-themes
```

You can also add your own themes in case you are not happy with the available ones (as explained [here](https://github.com/sharkdp/bat#adding-new-themes)).